# Joi validate 1-2 length array of numbers where the first must be less than the second

Tags: javascript, joi

I'm trying to validate an array of numbers that is 1-2 elements in length, the numbers are also limited to a range of -60 and 60. I can't figure out how to validate that the first element must be less than the second.

Sample of my code:

```
a: joi.array().items(joi.number().min(-60).max(60)).min(1).max(2)
 .required()
 .error(() => ''))
```

Answer (score 1):

Joi has a [sort](https://joi.dev/api/?v=17.8.3#arraysortoptions) method for arrays.
In your case, the solution would be

```js
{
  a: Joi.array()
       .min(1).max(2).required()
       .items(Joi.number().min(-60).max(60).strict(true))
       .sort({
         order: "ascending",
     }).strict()
}
```

Which means that field `a` is a required array with a minimum length of 1 and a maximum length of 2. Its elements are strictly numbers (no number string), the minimum being -60 and the maximum being 60 (range of -60 to 60).
Its items must be sorted in an ascending order.

To include an error message for this, [check array sort error](https://joi.dev/api/?v=17.8.3#arraysortoptions)